# Data not posted for custom operation

Tags: laravel-backpack

I've got very big trouble with custom operations in Laravel backpack.
The documentated setup is clear but lack a real exemple with a form.
In my case I wanted to use the form engine to create a form for a relationship.

First step I did this :

```
public function getProtocoleForm($id)
    {
        // Config base 
        $this->crud->hasAccessOrFail('update');
        $this->crud->setOperation('protocole');

        // 
        $this->crud->addFields([
            [   'name' => 'codeCim',
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => 'Code CIM',
            ],
        ]);

        $this->crud->addSaveAction([
            'name' => 'save_action_protocole',
            'visible' => function($crud) {
                return true;
            },
            'button_text' => 'Ajouter le procotole',
            'redirect' => function($crud, $request, $itemId) {
                return $crud->route;
            },
        ]);

        // get the info for that entry
        $this->data['entry'] = $this->crud->getEntry($id);
        $this->data['crud'] = $this->crud;
        $this->data['saveAction'] = $this->crud->getSaveAction();
        $this->data['title'] = 'Protocole ' . $this->crud->entity_name;

        return view('vendor.backpack.crud.protocoleform', $this->data);
    }
```

This is working fine, the form appears on the screen, then I did a setup for a post route like this :

```
Route::post($segment . '/{id}/protocolestore', [
      'as'        => $routeName . '.protocolestore',
      'uses'      => $controller . '@storeProtocole',
      'operation' => 'protocole',
]);
```

The route appears correctly when I execute the artisan command but the `storeProtocole` function is never called. I checked the generated HTML and the form action is correct and checking in the "network" panel of the browser is also targeting the correct route.

Can you help me and tell me where I missed something ?

[Quick update] I made a mistake, the form route is not good in the HTML, it takes the route of the main controller.

Comment: I am stuck with the same issue and I couldn't believe it but the doc really doesn't include a proper example with a form

Comment: I am stuck here too, did anyone get it to work?